# 302 redirect to non-HTTP protocol

Tags: php, web-applications, http-redirect

I need to perform a 302 redirect with PHP. I'm trying with header location.

It works well with HTTP. But, the redirect does not work with a custom protocol.  For example:

```
header ('Location: magplus://myaccountview/login/');
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: @Brad Not really. The Location header is part of the `HTTP` protocol after all.

Answer (score 7):

For some browsers, you will not be able to redirect to a protocol other than HTTP or HTTPS.  There is nothing you can do about that specifically.

You can try to change the location in the browser client-side with JavaScript, if that is a possibility for your application.  That also won't always work however.